# orientation change in landscape mode

Tags: android

my code is below but not call this method when screen orientation changed .

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig
            Intent in=new Intent("com.world.delailsActivity")
                          startActivity(in)
}
```

and mainfest.xml file is

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".WorldCup" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
                    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ScoreActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.worldcup.ScoreActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: I can't see any com.world.delailsActivity defined in your Manifest; or maybe your intent should call for com.worldcup.ScoreActivity?

Answer (score 1):

In your first Activity, your android:configChanges attribute should be in your activity element, not category.